# path settings in asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, filepath

I am working on a website (which has more than 2 projects in it). The other team has developed thing this site partially. While going through this i am facing few issues in understanding the code.

There is a link which is navigating to a page of another site. The url given to this is

http://mywebsite.com/testsearch/nvalue/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The page which is opening through this url is textpage.aspx which is located at the main root of the mywebsite project, "nvalue" is some text coming from previous site (where the link is clicked). xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is some encrypted value.

The above url looks as if testsearch is a folder where there is no such folder.

I am not understanding how the above url works and why its given so

Can anyone give some information on this.

Thanks in advance
Pavan

Comment: look for UrlRewrite to understand what they do

Answer (score 0):

The url must be getting overwritten in the target site , this is posible using URL Rewriting.

Check the web.config or global.asax or IIS for URL Rewriting rules, it must be present somewhere direct or using http modules.

Better ask the old developer.